# Edit option in Android tableLayout like in iphone UITableView

Tags: android

I need to have an edit option in **tableLayout** just like in iphone **UITableView**. When edit button is clicked a **Delete** button should appear in each row of tableLayout. What I just did was I created a **Delete** button in each row at runtime and made it hide. And when **Edit** button is clicked, **Delete button** gets visible. But I don't think it seems to be a good practice.
Is there an inbuilt functionality for this? What is the best practice I should follow?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a seperate xml file containing only a delete button and then inflate it into all the rows when the edit button is clicked.That way you dont have to hide all those delete buttons and can add them only if needed...

Create a new xml file under res->layout and add only this to it

```
<Button
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/delete"
   android:layout_width="20sp"
   android:layout_height="20sp"
   android:padding="10sp">
  </Button>
```

Then just inflate it into your row.

```
//create inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

//inflate delete button.
//You can put this in a loop to have a delete button in all your rows.     
View delete_button = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURROWID,
            (ViewGroup) YOURROWNAME, false);
```

For more info this is a good tutorial to understand inflation- http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/26/layout-resources-in-android/
Good luck! :)

Comment: Can you give me some example for this.

Comment: Np I've edited my answer to include an example.See if it helps!

Comment: Thanks dragonfly. Your answer was very useful. I also wanted some help on navigation bar with tab bar. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ContextMenus. Long press on any row should give u a pop-up screen to delete that row. Implement onContextItemSelected to delete

Comment: Can you give me some example for this.

Comment: Refer to http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/